# Function variable can't be used because it hasn't been declared variable or isn't found

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create an application to give me Wikipedia links or random ideas from my lists of links and ideas to work on, but the chosen link or idea aren't an attribute from the functions.

I've tried to call the functions beforehand, reworking the variable names (with and without the function name)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.lang import Builder
import random, re


def wiki_list(*kargs):
    File=r'‪C:\Users\David\Desktop\Wiki.txt'
    links=re.findall(r'(https?://[^\s]+)', File)
    index=random.randint(1,len(links))
    wiki_list.wiki=links[index]

def rand_idea(*kargs):
    File=r'‪C:\Users\David\Desktop\Ideas.txt'
    ideas=re.findall(r'(https?://[^\s]+)', File)
    index=random.randint(1,len(ideas))
    rand_idea.idea=ideas[index]



Builder.load_string("""
<Test>:
    size_hint: 1, 1
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    do_default_tab: False
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Rando Wiki'
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Click Here For New Wiki Read'
            Label:
                text: '%s'
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Rando Ideas'
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Click Here For New Idea Read'
            Label:
                text: '%s'
""") % (wiki_list.wiki,rand_idea.idea)


class Test(TabbedPanel):
    pass
class TabbedPanelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    TabbedPanelApp().run()
```

This application should have a button that changes the idea and link on click(future feature), as of now I'm still trying to get it to print the link or idea.

Comment: You haven't called either function `wiki_list` or `rand_idea` at the time you're calling `Builder.load_string()`, so the attributes you've hung off these functions do not exist. Maybe call the functions at some point?

Comment: You may want to rethink those functions. For instance `wiki_list` doesn't use its input arguments, doesn't `return` a value, and you don't `open` the `File` so the regex is going to search the file path string for the URL pattern instead of searching the contents of the file. While it's possible in Python to append arbitrary info to a function in the body of that same function (like `wiki_list.wiki=**`), consider whether that is the best design strategy.